# How to lock API from 3d party mobile app?

Tags: api, lockdown

I need to use some API by my own mobile app. But I want lock access from 3d party mobile apps. How can I do this?

I talking not about authorization. I just don't want, that somebody write application which use API on my website.

Comment: What have you tried? What OS are you developing for? If you are going to ask a question at least put some effort.

Comment: iOS, Android. I don't think that OS is important in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reliably block 3rd party clients without machine to machine authentication.

I suggest using an [API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963877/creating-an-api-for-mobile-applications-authentication-and-authorization) as a general approach. This question explains [how it might be implemented at a high level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386930/rest-api-authorization-authentication-web-mobile/9387289#9387289)

However:

What's best for you depends entirely on the framework that you're using, it's always best to use an existing framework for security.